# HSQLDB-based library very slow: trying to narrow down search for bug

Tags: java, caching, hsqldb

I integrated a 3rd-party library into my Java project. This library depends on `HSQLDB.jar`. This library -- and thus the version of `HSQLDB.jar` that came with it -- is a bit old, last updated in 2010. It's also pretty large. In my code, I loop over data points and call the library to perform some calculations. What I noticed is the time required for processing grows more or less exponentially with the number of data point. For example, for 100 points, the difference compared to the version not using the library is tiny; for 2000 points the difference is about an hour; for 5000 points it takes a couple of days to complete compared to a couple of hours without it!

I tried updating `HSQLDB.jar` to the latest version but that a bunch of exceptions so I reverted back to the old one.

I ran `hprof` and it reported that a very large portion of total time is spent in `org.hsqldb.persist.Cache.cleanUp`. What I am trying to do now is somehow narrow down my search for what the problem is and/or where it occurs. Since it's only noticeable when a lot of input data is processed, I want to do some preliminary "triage" before I start doing debugging runs.

Unfortunately, at this point I can't show any code excerpts here since I don't know what excerpts are relevant...

So my question is this: does the fact that it's spending too much time in `org.hsqldb.persist.Cache.cleanUp` indicate the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time spent in  `org.hsqldb.persist.Cache.cleanUp` shows it has a small memory cache setting which results in frequent purges and reads from the cache.

You can shutdown the application and manually edit the .script file of the database with larger cache settings.

The details are in the HSQLDB Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html

You can find the exact version of the database in the .properties file and download the zip package for that version from SourceForge and refer to its guide for maximum allowed values.

Comment: Thank you! I am seeing `SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000` and `SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000` in my script file. I can try making these larger. However, the data points I am processing are totally independent of each other. Does the behavior of my system suggest that there is some sort of leakage in the system and that, regardless of how big the cache is, it will eventually slow to a crawl or crash after I process enough data? My system is intended to be run as a server processing incoming data 24/7

Comment: No leakage is likely. The speed depends how they mapped the points to database rows. In general, if all the accessed points fit in the cache, it will perform in-memory in O(log n).